# How can we get multiple collection's product data at the single API call in shopify?

Tags: php, api, shopify

I need multiple collection's products using the Shopify API. I have already read their documents. In that If I am passing collection id then it is giving me that collection's data. But I need multiple collection product data using a single API call. Is it possible?
Please help me.

```
Referred Link: https://shopify.dev/docs/admin-api/rest/reference/products/collection#products-2020-10
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

If you examine the GraphQL API for the Product endpoint, you'll see one of the handy attributes is a list of collections holding the product. Since there can be many collections holding the product, this attribute comes with cursors, ensuring you can get all of them when needed. That is your best bet.